# Modify pre-defined wizard page

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way to modify (or replace) a pre-defined Inno Setup wizard page from the script code? I would like to place some informative bitmap and text on the (otherwise unused) bottom part of the "Installing" wizard page, or do similar (mainly static, non-functional) modifications to other wizard pages.

Note: this question is not about creating a completely new custom pages - that's clear, widely used and documented.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an answer myself. It is vaguely hinted at here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses .

So I plan to access the WizardForm.InstallingPage (or other page) from the InitializeWizard procedure. That should do it.

(after having tried it - e.g.:)

```
procedure InitializeBillboard;
var
  Page: TNewNotebookPage;
begin
  Page := WizardForm.InstallingPage;

  BillboardBitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(Page);
  BillboardBitmapImage.Left := 0;
  BillboardBitmapImage.Width := 416;
  BillboardBitmapImage.Top := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top + WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Height + 16;
  BillboardBitmapImage.Height := 146;
  BillboardBitmapImage.OnClick := @BillboardBitmapImage_OnClick;
  BillboardBitmapImage.Parent := Page;
end;
```

Comment: You are not going to *access* the `WizardForm.InstallingPage` page. You are going to create components whose `Parent` will be that page.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I planned to do. You have put it in more precise words. I have now added the resulting code to my answer.

Comment: Yes, because you should be precise in programming. To your code, set the `Parent` as the very first thing after you create a component. It's not just an unwritten law, but it's sometimes required to get proper results when you are using parent relative positioning.